# Ghostscript 9.26 build fails on PowerPC (ppc64le) architecture

Tags: python, ghostscript, powerpc, rhel7

I am trying to build Ghostscript 9.26 on rhel 7.6 ppc64le. However the make command fails with:

ERROR:

```
./sobin/libgs.so: undefined reference to  
     'png_init_filter_functions_vsx'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Python version: Python 3.6.3
Environment : Rhel 7.6 ppc64le
Pip: pip 20.0.2 from /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Would like some help on this issue. I am running it on a High end VM with good connectivity.

Comment: See https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702236. Note that Python is, of course, completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding PNG_POWERPC_VSX_OPT=0 to your CFLAGS and trying with that.

make soclean

./configure CFLAGS="-DPNG_POWERPC_VSX_OPT=0"

make so

Comment: FWIW, we did just release 9.52, so it would be in your interest to update to that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I encountered the same problem when trying to compile GDAL 3.2.0 on ppc64le today! :)